# Install older version of gcc cross compiler for arm on Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04, libc

I need to use gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi version 6.5, along with a version of libc that came out around the same period (I believe is libc-2.26). My host system is Ubuntu 18.04.

If I go with just a simple

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

I'll get v7 for the gcc cross compiler and v2.30 for binutills, which does not work for me, since I'll end up with errors similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830355/targetting-an-older-version-of-libstdc-with-recent-gcc-when-cross-copiling-to).

If I try to download the deb packages, I get unmet dependencies.

I have also tried to force apt-get to install specific versions, using something like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) but I get error messages that the version I'm looking for cannot be found.

Is there a way to force ubuntu to install specific (older) version of gcc, libc, etc.?
I know that gcc v 6 is obsolete, but I cannot do otherwise.

Comment: also note that the gnu arm cross compilers were not apt gettable forever, they started not too long ago (relatively) and as such the gcc/binutils versions would have been from that time frame.   but the linaro and others have been around much longer and you can still get most/all of those versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to the Linaro release of gcc 6.5, available [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/), which comes with glibc version 2.23.

Comment: Glad to read that, would you in this case consider accepting my answer ? Thanks.